# What is the correct way to list pipelines in ElasticTranscoder using PHP SDK version3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am getting an error with the following code

```
use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient;

# Region where the sample will be run.
$region = 'us-east-1';
$version = 'latest';

# Create the client for Elastic Transcoder.
$transcoder_client = ElasticTranscoderClient::factory(array(        
    'version' => $version,
    'region' => $region, 
    'default_caching_config' => '/tmp'
));

$result = $transcoder_client->listPipelines();
```

The errors are:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\ElasticTranscoder\Exception\ElasticTranscoderException' with message ' in /home/soulandsurvival.org/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 192

and

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/pipelines` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"message":"Signature expired: 20160408T084817Z is now earlier than 20160411T011427Z (20160411T011927Z - 5 min.)"} in /home/soulandsurvival.org/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 107